# JMX in Spring: Is MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean Thread-Safe

Tags: spring, jmx

I have a spring based web-application that needs to get data from ActiveMQ via a JMX connection.
I am using `MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean` (in Spring) to get various MBean attributes from ActiveMQ.

I have only one `MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean` as a member variable, which is used to get the data. If multiple requests/threads come concurrently will there be any issues? Will there be any race conditions?

Please suggest the best way to keep the code thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

Spring `FactoryBean` objects are not intended to be used directly from your code, they're supposed to be used in your Spring config. As such, they are designed to be executed once and once only.

If you want to use them, including `MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean`, then you need to create them, configure them, use them and discard them each and every time you want to get the object they create. They are most definitely *not* thread-safe.

Better yet, do it as the design intended and use them in your Spring config.

Comment: Thanks alot for replying.
Initially I had made the MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean in the Spring config. But then  on startup of my application it tries to make a connection to the ActiveMQ(mBean Server). 
Now if ActiveMQ server is off then a connection cannot be made. 
Even on starting the ActiveMQ server the JMX connection cannot be established.
I had no option left but to move the MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean into the code and try to establish connections when a request came in.
This lead to the question on thread-safety as i had a member variable for the connection.
Please help.

Comment: @user736492: Read the documentation for `MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean` more closely.  It has options for deferring the connection attempt until it is required, rather than doing it on startup.

Comment: Yes it has an option to create a connection when used the first time(Instead of on startup). But this probably only attempts a connection the first time(one time). It will not try to reattempt connections in case the activeMQ server was off at the time. Thus it probably wont solve my issue of reattempting connection for each request from a browser.

Comment: Hi, is there any way to reattempt connections to the mbean server.